# Where can I find Ral Partha miniatures for cheap?

Tags: miniatures

I live in Canada and I own a few of the old Ral Partha D&D miniatures which are pretty cool. Unfortunately, I haven't seen them for sale anywhere for the last couple of years. I checked out a couple of the other questions here such as: "Where can I find miniatures for AD&D monsters", and "Where can I find fantasy miniatures on the cheap". These threads had some great resources. However, the best price I could find on the old Ral Partha miniatures was $50 for two 15mm miniatures on Noble Knight Games.

So, basically I was wondering if anyone still sells cheap and cool metal miniatures for fantasy RPG games? If they're all collector items now, or anyone has any other ideas, they'd be much appreciated. Thanks! E-bay and Amazon are tough for me to work with because most of it's based in the U.S. If the shipping is reasonable, that would be nice too.

Comment: It's not Ral Partha (so not posting as an answer), but [Reaper Miniatures](http://www.reapermini.com/) is still in business and the quality of the sculpts (pewter and new resins) are comparable to the old Ral Partha. Being American, the shipping may be more reasonable than from Ral Partha Europe. It's no help if you're looking for particular Ral Partha sculpts, of course.

Comment: Where are you shipping to?

Comment: Canageek: Alberta, Canada. SevenSidedDie: that's awesome. Thanks so much. I know I asked about Ral Partha in particular, but really I'm just looking for good metal miniatures. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm going to yank the [dnd-miniatures] tag since that specifically refers to Wizards of the Coast's "D&D Miniatures" product line.

Comment: I've closed this as too localized because this answer is going to change fairly regularly, and so is not going to be of long term use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is [Iron Wind Metals](http://ironwindmetals.com/store/index.php?cPath=47&osCsid=02c8b3e6473493d7bf6957ecc7c4447a), which is the descendant of Ral Partha. Here's a quote from wikipedia;

> In late 2001 Ral Partha was spun off from WizKids and renamed Iron
>   Wind Metals, LLC, with longtime general manager Michael Noe as
>   president. Iron Wind Metals reestablished production with Mark
>   Rubin, an original owner, and much of the same staff, molds, and
>   license agreements. They continue to use the name Ral Partha in
>   reference to the early designs and produce figures under license from
>   Ral Partha-era sculptors.

Have you checked [Ral Partha's European](http://www.ralparthaeurope.co.uk/)  site? I know you live in Canada, but they may be able to ship to you if you agree to pay extra shipping charges. Also, [Paizo's Ral Partha page](http://paizo.com/store/sale/americanEagles/ralPartha) has a meager collection.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was just checking out the Ral Partha European site. It looks like it has a great selection.

Comment: Iron Wind Metals looks awesome. Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, but I will tell you that in my opinion Reapers is better than Ral Partha in almost every way.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice! I didn't know Reapers was so good. Wow, they have a great selection and the prices are reasonable too. Thanks again!